# Create and update an object for an element of an array? Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, andengine

This question is about AndEngine/Android but pertains also to Java. I have an NPC class in my game that when the player gets close to them, I want them to show a message by creating a rectangle/text above them. I have multiple NPCs that I create and I add them to an array called NPCbody. I want to use a for loop to draw a rectangle/text above each of them if they are close to the player. I can do this, but the only problem is, with this code I have now, they do not detach from the scene. It is filled up with rectangles where the player was close to the NPC. So how can I have these rectangles that I created be only created ONCE for each NPC, and updated?

```
try {
        if (NPCbody.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NPCbody.size(); i++) {
                final Rectangle NPCmessageRectangle;
                final Text NPCmessageText;

                NPCmessageRectangle = new Rectangle(NPCx - 50, NPCy + 175, 200, 50,
                        vbom);
                NPCmessageRectangle.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                NPCmessageRectangle.setAlpha(90);
                NPCmessageText = new Text(NPCx, NPCy, resourcesManager.smallFont,
                        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890.,!?\" ", vbom);
                NPCmessageText.setText("");
                attachChild(NPCmessageText);
                NPCmessageText.setVisible(false);
                attachChild(NPCmessageRectangle);
                NPCmessageRectangle.setVisible(false);
                NPCx = NPCbody.get(i).getPosition().x * 32;
                NPCy = NPCbody.get(i).getPosition().y * 32;
                NPCmessage = npc.getNPCmessage();
                NPCmessageText.setText(NPCmessage);
                NPCmessageText.setPosition(NPCx, NPCy + 50);
                NPCmessageRectangle.setX(NPCx);
                NPCmessageRectangle.setY(NPCy + 50);
                if (isDistance(player.getX(), player.getY(), NPCx, NPCy,
                        150)) {
                    NPCmessageRectangle.setVisible(true);
                    NPCmessageText.setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("Rectangle set visible for NPC "+i);
                } else {
                    NPCmessageRectangle.setVisible(false);
                    NPCmessageText.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

(This code is part of a method that is repeatedly called.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a "messageDisplayed" variable in each NPC class. That variable would be a reference to the text message you create. If that variable is non-null, then skip creating the text object.

You have to remember to:
Remove the text objects. 
Set the reference back to null again when its removed so that a new rectangle will appear.

As and aside, you may want to create a pool of these text bubble shapes so that you do not have to keep creating a new one each time one is needed.